# LAD with L2 norm in python? (sklearn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to implement the LAD version of the linear_model.Ridge() in sklearn. Meaning the regularization is still done on the L2 norm but the model minimizes the sum of the absolute deviations not the squares of the errors. Meaning we're minimizing [image]

Is that possible?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but not really on-topic  here on SO. Maybe asking on `gitter` is a better option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [SGDRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor) in scikit learn with the *epsilon_insensitive* loss function specified and the *epsilon* value set to zero, you will get a model equivalent to LAD with L2 regularization.